# Show existence of power series that meets the condition of the differential equation $y''-xy=0, y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Let $y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, I want to find a power series that satisfies 
$$
y''-xy = 0, y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0
$$

My attempt:

$$
y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n  
$$
$$
y'(x) =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1} 
$$
$$
y''(x) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}
$$
Reindexing the $n$ in $y''(x)$, we have 
$$
y''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}
$$

Now I have $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+1} = 0$, but how can I proceed to find $a_n$? Or at least show that such a series exists?

Comment: Compare coefficients of $x^n$ both sides of the equation. The zero function must have every coefficient equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, formally you can agroup the two sums in this way:
$$ 2a_{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left((n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}-a_{n-1}\right)x^n=0.$$
Differentiating succesively and putting $x=0$ we conclude that it's enough to compare de coefficients of each power of $x$ (remember the fact that the derivate of a power series converge in the same interval where the original serie does) This give us the following equations:
$$a_{2}=0, 6a_{3}-a_{0}= 0, 12a_4-a_{1}=0, 20a_{5}-a_{2}=0,30a_{6}-a_{3}=0,...$$
Hence we necessarily have 
$$0=a_{2}=a_{5}=a_{8}=a_{11}=\cdots=a_{3n+2}=\cdots.$$
We also have 
$$a_{3}=\frac{a_0}{2\cdot 3}, a_{6}=\frac{a_3}{6\cdot 5}=\frac{a_0}{6\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 2}, a_9= \frac{a_6}{9\cdot 8}=\frac{a_0}{9\cdot 8\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 2},...$$
hence 
$$a_{3n}=\frac{a_0}{3n\cdot(3n-1)\cdot(3n-3)\cdot(3n-4)\cdots 3\cdot 2}$$
In the same way we have
$$a_{4}=\frac{a_1}{4\cdot 3}, a_7=\frac{a_4}{7\cdot 6}=\frac{a_1}{7\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 3},...$$
so $a_{3n+1}=\frac{a_1}{(3n+1)\cdot 3n\cdots 4\cdot 3}.$
It remains to determine $a_0$ and $a_1.$ For this note that $a_0=y(0)=1$ and
$0=y'(0)=a_{1}.$ Therefore, the power series solution should be 
$$y(x)= 1+ \frac{x^3}{3\cdot 2}+\frac{x^6}{6\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot 2}+\cdots.$$

PS: note that this serie has infinite convergence radio and please excuse my english. By the way, I am not sure if it is neccesary but I think it should be checked if, with these $a_n$'s, the series $\sum (n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^{n}$ and $\sum a_n x^{n+1}$ converge (to make the first line of my answer be valid)

Answer (score 0):

You can make replacement
$$ y'=yz$$ 
$$ z^2+z'-x=0$$